# Issue with PlayReady in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uwp, drm, playready

I have an issue running PlayReady protected streams in my UWP app. When I set the source on a MediaElement it fails with this error:

MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0x8007023F

I have tried the official samples from MS (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PlayReady-samples-for-124a3738) and a sample app from Davide Zordan (https://github.com/davidezordan/playready_adaptive_UWP/). They all throws the error.

If I run a normal SmoothStream I don't seam to have any issues.

I'm pretty sure that the samples are solid and it comes down to a missing SDK or something on my computer(s). I have added the SmoothStreaming Client SDK for UWP apps. I can reproduce the error on 5 different developer machines.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

OK I found the issue. Im working on one computer and remotes to my development machines located at my office. Turns out that by default PlayReady is disabled when using remote desktop.

Comment: Indeed, that's the correct reason. It probably has to do with [COPP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).